# Using bash: Remove list of directory names from a file containing said directory names and other text

Tags: bash, list, variables, directory, string-comparison

I have a text file containing 100s of directory names, one per line.

Such as:

```
Directory1
Directory2
etc...
```

I have a directory filled with subdirectories named let's say Directory5 through Directory10.

The actual directories are not in numerical order, but rather: text_randomtext

I would like to remove the subdirectory names from the list and create a new modified list.

Attempted using bash/grep using variables, but am not having any luck:

```
#!/bin/bash

for name in 'find . -name 'text_*'' ; do
  grep -v "${name}" textfile1.lst > tmpfile && mv tmpfile textfile2.lst
done
```

Thanks for any help

EDIT: To try to make it more clear. The file contains a list of subdirectories. I have a group of subdirectories within the list that I'd like remove from the list to make a new list. The group of subdirectories, however, are not listed in a file format. Instead they are only within a common directory.

My plan was to have list1 (containing all subdirectories). Then somehow turning the smaller group of subdirectories into a second list, list2, maybe using their common parent directory? Using list2 to then remove those subdirectories from list1, to make a new updated list1, newlist1, that contains all subdirectories except for those in list2.

So in my attempt above, I tried turning the names of the subdirectories within the current parent directory into the variable 'name.' Then using grep to find the strings in 'name' to remove them from textfile.lst. This would output textfile2.lst which would contain the names of all subdirectories except for those contained in the variable 'name.'

Answer (score 0):

If the directories and other text is in `file.txt` and you want the lines that are not directories, you can run

```
comm -23 <(sort file.txt) <(find . -type d -depth 1 -exec basename -a {} + | sort)
```

as `comm` selects or rejects lines common to two files, `-23` suppresses column 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to remove folders:

First, create a .sh file and paste this code into that file.

```
#!/bin/bash

folders_file="list.txt"

# Loop through each line in the file
while IFS= read -r folder || [[ -n "$folder" ]]; do
    # Remove the folder
    rm -rf "$folder"
    echo "Removed folder: $folder"
done < "$folders_file"
```

Then run on the terminal:

```
bash name_your_file.sh
```